# Proof of identification of causal effect in high dimensional mediation analysis

Tags: references, causality, mediation, high-dimensional

I'm studying [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2022.2053136?journalCode=uasa20) for high-dimensional mediation analysis for a class project. Section 2 of this paper talks about different assumptions being made for identifying causal effects. But my instructor wants me to prove identification step by step using graphical analyses or probabilistic arguments. She mentioned that sometimes people would need frontdoor/backdoor adjustments for assumptions like exchangeability, stable-unit value assumption, consistency, and positivity. Is there any reference or proof in any paper that explains the identification of the estimands for high-dimensional mediation analysis for common assumptions?